# Number of ways of sending postcards to friends

Tags: combinatorics

In a store there are $k$ types of postcards. I want to send some postcards to $n$ family members.
(1) In how many different ways can this be done?
(2) What happens if we want to send them different cards?
(3) What happens if we
want to send two different cards to each of them?

So I assume for (1), there are $k^n$ ways to do this. Then for (2), if we want to send each person a different card, there are $nk$ ways to do that because each person can receive each of the types of cards as long as nobody else has received it. For (3), $nk/2$ would be the answer because we have $n$ people and $k$ cards but each person is receiving twice as many cards which reduces the amount of unique cards available. Does this look correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The reasoning for (1) is correct. That for (2) is not: different cards can be sent iff $k\ge n$, and in that case there are $\frac{k!}{(k-n)!}={}^kP_n$ ways to send the cards.

For (3), each family member can receive two different cards in $\binom k2$ ways, so there are $\binom k2^n$ ways to send cards to all $n$ members in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

$1)$ Looks good.

$2)$ Consider lining up all your family members. Then the person on the leftmost side has $k$ possibilities, person $2$ has $k-1$ possibilities, person $3$ has $k-2$ possibilities, etc. Doing this for all $n$ people gives

$$k\cdot(k-1)\cdot(k-2)\cdots(k-(n-1))=\frac{k!}{(k-n)!}$$

$3)$ For each individual person, the amount of combinations of cards that person can get is $k\choose{2}$ cards. Doing this for all $n$ people we get $${k\choose{2}}^n$$